# SQL Server query returns incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database to use in SQL Server. The tables are:

- Price (prodID, from, price)
- Product (prodID, name, quantity)
- PO (prodID, orderID, amount)
- Order (orderID, date, address, status, trackingNumber, custID, shipID)
- Shipping (shipID, company, time, price)
- Customer (custID, name)
- Address (addrID, custID, address)

I am trying to find the total price of each order (which is the total price of each product ordered by the `date` attribute in the `Order` table plus the total shipping price for that order), but the catch is that each product has multiple prices associated with it depending on the date it was ordered aka the `from` attribute in the `Price` table.

My current query is this:

```
select o.orderID, sum(p.price+s.price) as total_cost
from [Order] as o
inner join PO as po on o.orderId = po.orderId
inner join Price as p on p.prodId = po.prodId
inner join Shipping as s on o.shipId = s.shipId
group by o.orderId
order by o.orderId;
```

This query returns the correct `orderID`s but returns higher than expected `total_cost`

I know that I need subqueries to extract the correct prices for each product but I am unsure of where or how to use them in this case. I am also not sure my main query is even close to what I want.

A piece of sample data from my query has orderID 1 having a total cost of $17971.15 while the expected result for ID 1 is $388.68.

My goal is to have the `orderID` and the total price for each order which also includes the shipping price.

Comment: Show some sample data, actual results and expected results.

Comment: Done, I was only given one expected result, so I only have one point of reference to add to the post.

Comment: You need to give us something to test with, otherwise known as a [mre], that makes your life easier too - if you create a small set of fake sample data to test with. And really we need you to create the temp tables and populate them (DDL+DML) to we can copy and paste it out and test it. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key issue starts with the `price` table - from your question as

> Price (prodID, from, price)

You really want this to be in the format of a date range e.g., `prodID, dateFrom, dateTo, price`.

You can do this with a LEAD function (getting the next 'from', and calling it 'dateto')

```
SELECT prod_ID, [from] as datefrom, LEAD([from],1) OVER (PARTITION BY prodID ORDER BY [from]) AS dateto, [price]
FROM Price
```

To get the relevant price for a given order date, use the above as a virtual table rather than the price table and find the price as at the relevant date (between the datefrom and dateto, with the link to dateto being a 'less than' rather than 'less than or equal to') e.g.,

```
select o.orderID, s.price AS Shipping_price, sum(PO.amount * p.price) as item_Price
from [Order] as o
inner join PO as po on o.orderId = po.orderId
inner join Shipping as s on o.shipId = s.shipId
inner join 
    (SELECT prod_ID, [from] as datefrom, LEAD([from],1) OVER (PARTITION BY prodID ORDER BY [from]) AS dateto, [price]
    FROM Price
    ) as p on p.prodId = po.prodId AND o.[date] >= p.[datefrom] AND o.[date] < [dateto]
group by o.orderId, s.price
order by o.orderId;
```

Note in the above

- Total cost for items is calculated as item price * number of items (not just the base price for the item)
- I have separated shipping cost in the above - I imagine that it is by order (rather than by item) whereas your question includes the shipping once per item.

Note that @Dale's comments are important - the above code is completely untested and may have SQL errors etc. As we don't have sample data etc, I cannot run it to ensure it works. But hopefully it sets you on the correct path.

I do suggest you run a logic check over your result when finished e.g., if you order 5 bananas @ $1.50 each, with shipping $8, your total cost should be $15.50

Comment: It's hard to create some test data when you do not know how the original database creates the tables in the first place but I do agree that it would have been helpful. Also, how do I combine the shipping_price and item_price into one column?

Comment: You could use `s.price + sum(PO.amount * p.price)`; alternatively, put the answer into a sub-query and add the two figures. Note that if either of those is NULL, then adding them also results in NULL, so if free shipping is left as NULL for price you'll need to add `ISNULL(s.price,0)` (or coalesce, etc) rather than just `s.price`.

Comment: That was an easier solution than I expected. I guess now I just need to do some intense research.